# Function to find not only the minium value of a sequence, but also its index in F#

Tags: list, f#, idioms

I have a sequence and I need to find both the minimum value of the sequence, and that value's index in the sequence - effectively some sort of "Seq.mini" function along the lines of Seq.mapi or Seq.iteri.

What's the cleanest / most idiomatic way of expressing this in F#?

Idiomatically, should I be expecting to write a function that returns a tuple (value, index) or (index, value) and if so is there a convention for which order these values should appear?

One other thing: If there is more than one element with the same minimum value, I need the index of the first occurrence - I guess this translates into a strictly "less than (<)" comparison rather than "less than or equal to (<=)" - correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple clean solution:

```
let mini s = s |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x)) |> Seq.minBy snd
let index, value = seq [3;6;1;5;1] |> mini
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks! I was able to combine this with the tuple function from Ramon's answer to replace the lambda for something which looks readable and makes sense (to me)

Comment: Just a thought: if the function is the first argument to mini and the sequence the second, it will be consistent with the F# collection functions, `let mini f s = s |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x)) |> Seq.minBy f`

Answer (score 1):

I will factor that more, and define two generally-useful functions.

```
(* Infinite sequence of whole numbers. 0 .. *)
let indices = Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some(x, x + 1)) 0

(* Zips the given sequence with indices of elements. *)
let zipWithIndex coll = Seq.zip coll indices

printfn "%A" ([12; 8; 9; 90; 3; 24] |> zipWithIndex |> Seq.minBy fst) // prints (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
let tuple a b = a, b
let uncurry f (a, b) = f a b

module Seq =
    let inline miniBy f seq =
        (Seq.mapi tuple
        >> Seq.minBy (uncurry f)) seq

Seq.miniBy (fun i x -> x) [ 4; 6; 3; 7; 2; 2; 7 ]
```

?

The predicate function receives the index, but in this case has no need to use it.

**Note:** `miniBy : (int -> 'a -> 'b) -> seq<'a> -> int * 'a when 'b : comparison`

Comment: I don't know how to call this - sorry, I'm an f# newbie. I had to define tuple and uncurry myself (these aren't built-in anywhere are they?) to get rid of compiler errors, but they're pretty straight-forward. But I'm still not sure how to call it. Also, I actually have a list rather than a sequence, but this doesn't work: miniBy seq myList

Comment: Does this help: `Seq.miniBy (fun index value -> 2 * index + value) [ 1 .. 5 ]`? The resulting type would be `int * int` (one `int` from the index, the other from the value).

Comment: Added an edit, to show tuple, uncurry and an example of how to call the function.